# Python cheetah variables inside a #raw javascript block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, cheetah

If I have a block of #raw that has javascript inside it and sometimes I need to access some python variables (the $foo in example case) from that javascript.

```
#raw

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >
    if ( 
        #end raw
          $foo
        #raw
        and $('#manuf').val() )  {
          getNextFreeProdCode(
            $('#category option:selected').val(),
            $('#subCat option:selected').val(),
            $('#manuf option:selected').val()
           );
        }
  </script>
#end raw
```

first of all, that looks ugly and not so readable code. I would like to have if operator in single line.

But is there:

- a way to introduce those variables with some placeholders like %s in
  python strings?
- Or some way to tell #raw what that block is and give
  those variables for it as an argument? Like:

  `#raw($foo, $bar)
     .
     if ( $(#manuf).val() or $foo ) {
        fooBar($bar);
     .
     .
     .
     }
   #end raw`

  just like in #def define block allows arguments like function call.

Actually I would like the second way more, and maybe it shouldn't be called #raw but it could be raw-content-specific, like #ecmascript() ... #end ecmascript?

Maybe there is already a solution for this?

Juha

Comment: In this case I would just skip the #raw-blocks and use jQuery('#manuf').val()  etc instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is either raw or not raw, i.e. parsed. If you want parsed variables inside a block the block cannot be raw. You have to escape dollar signs inside a parsed block.

Comment: Yep, there is need for something semiraw that would have placeholders and accept arguments.

Comment: I'm afraid we're not there yet :)

Comment: Actually I don't think it's possible at all.